# Interacting with a web server using AJAX and c++/cli

Tags: c++, ajax, c++-cli, ajax.net, wt

I am writing a desktop program which I want to register on the first use through the web.  on the registration it should get a message from the website of ok or not-ok.

I think that this interaction is very similar to AJAX, but my porgram is written in c++/cli.

What is the best way to interact with my website (server)?

I saw there are libraries for c++ and AJAX.

Mainly I saw wt and AJAX.NET.

Would AJAX.NET work with c++/cli?

is wt a good library for AJAX considering I have only one call to the server, isn't it an "overkill".

What is the simplest way to send a simple ajax request to my website (server)?  Do I need a library at all?

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question, as you seem to be asking for opinions rather than concrete answers to a specific problem, but if I was approaching this situation I would definitely use an existing  library. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel

Comment: AJAX is absolutely not relevant here whatsoever. I suspect that you really want a SOAP service on the web server, and a SOAP client in your C++/CLI app.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Wt .. their hello world app is a good place to start:

- [Working Demo](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/examples/hello/hello.wt)
- [Simple Source code](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/examples/html/hello_8C_source.html)

I reckon have a play with that, and see how you feel about integrating it with your app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want your application to do some HTTP requests (to a distant web server), so you need an HTTP client library usable from C++.

You could use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) for that purpose (it is a C library with HTTP client ability). If your application is graphical and uses Qt/KDE, you could also use the [QtNetwork](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtnetwork.html) module or the `QFtp` or `QHttp` classes. If it uses Gtk/Gnome, use the [libsoup](http://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/) library